# Feature request: Creating a new tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I came accross this channel from my question:

[How to start with Speaker Verification?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53529/how-to-start-with-speaker-verification)

Actually in the question in the above link i was asking 'How to kick-start with the model development and what sorts of the steps could be useful for me.' Though its pretty hard to enlist all the steps, still expert in those field can share experience they've gained helping a new comer in the data-science in the abstract level.

But i din't found any of the tag corresponding to the situation I've faced as described above.

Comment: A lack of tags maybe a good indication that the topic are not covered here.